# Initializing pointers of structs through malloc

Tags: c

This is my following structs:

```
struct team {
    char* group_name;
    Driver driver1;
    Driver driver2;
} ;

struct season {
    int year;
    int groupNums;
    Team *teamArray;
    int numOfDrivers;
    Driver *driverArray;
};
```

this is how I initialized them each suitable header

```
typedef struct season* Season;
typedef struct team* Team;
```

I initialized the teamArray like this

```
season1->teamArray = (Team *)malloc(sizeof(Team)*teamNums);
```

ps: season1 is an input of type Season

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: There is no such thing as the right way. It depends on what you want, for instance a cleaner way to do it is `season1->teamArray = malloc(teamNums * sizeof(*season1->teamArray));` but whether this is right or not, depends on other things.

Comment: One thing, do not `typedef` pointers. That just makes the code confusing and difficult to understand, in exchange for absolutely no benefit but the ability to write code that is confusing and difficult to understand.

Comment: @Iharob are you against typedefing function pointers too?

Comment: @MFisherKDX What do you mean? Is there any real advantage in doing it? It's bad practice, notice that you say "*too*" for a reason. Any user of this site with good posts - *as opposed to high reputation* - has the same opinion, so why do YOU think it's worng? You do right?

Comment: @Iharob Don't read too much into "too". Just want to point out that it's quite beneficial to typedef function pointers. Typedefing struct season * is silly though -- and I agree that it hinders readability.